# Mixed conditionals sentences in english

Tags: sentence-construction, subjunctives, conditionals

Is below sentence construction correct?

"If I had any idea that you worked/work here, I would have contacted you."

After reading some articles regarding this sentences I read about 
Subordinate clause using with THAT. one rule says we can shift tense using subordinate clouse .

Eg
in my example if I use worked it may mean that the person is no longer work there at the time of speaking.

And if I use work it mean that the person is still working there .

Comment: We'd usually use ***any*** rather than ***an*** in such contexts. And as with *If you'd **told** me that you worked here, I'd have...*, we'd normally "backshift" ***work*** to ***worked***.

Comment: "If I had _had_ an/any idea..."

Answer (score 2):

It just needs some changes:
If I had **any** idea that you **worked** here**,** I would have contacted you.

Other examples:
If I was a good cook, I’d have invited them to lunch.

Comment: (It doesn't make a fat lot of difference with a <strong>comma</strong>, but I edited in the HTML tag that works in SO *Answer* text, where double asterisks don't. And as you can see from this comment, the SO platform is inconsistent in how it honours such flags anyway! :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. If I construct sentence with context. "Now I know you work here.  If I had any idea that you work here, I would have contacted you much before".