# Flipping through Tenses in sentences

Tags: sentence-construction

Context

I was not aware about who was doing what. When I come to know about the person who was handling that task I went to him, he helped me. Now I want tell him that,

"Thanks for your help. Now i come to know that you are taking care of this. If I had any idea that you (were/are) the one who takes care of this I would have contacted you much before."

My query about second part,

If I had any idea (In the past) 
that you (were/are) the one who takes care of this (fact)
I would have contacted you much before. (In the past)

Please help me should I use present tense or past tense (Were/are) in second part i.e. to tell fact?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixed conditionals sentences in english.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/238055/mixed-conditionals-sentences-in-english) (From a different user, but asking about *exactly* the same phrasing and context.)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could analyse this is:

> *"If I had any idea that you **were** the one who takes care of this, (...)"*
> He no longer takes care of that.

> *"If I had any idea that you **are** the one who takes care of this, (...)"*
> He is still in charge of that.

Answer (score 0):

"that" is a subordinate clause, hence one should take accounting of the Sequence of Tense, such as

> He said (that) he liked the idea.

more information can be found here: **https://www.learngrammar.net/english-grammar/correct-use-of-sequence-of-tense-in-writing**
or
https://www.thoughtco.com/that-clause-definition-1692539